# How to delete a particular child in firebase real time (Angular 7)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been stuck in trying to delete a particular child in my firebase real time database by a button click. A paginator is available with the list of the child i intend to delete on request.
Below is how far i have gone.I have tried all possible tutorial online but none seems to work.Either it deletes the entire parent node or it shows a successful message but nothing worked.

```
<div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="60%">
        <input matInput type="text" (keyup)="doFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>



<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="action-link">
            <a (click)="getID(item)">Approve</a> |
            <a (click)='delete(key,element)'>Delete</a>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> PhoneNumber </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.phone}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="cartype">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Car Type </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cartype}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="destination">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Destination</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.destination}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="time">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Time </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.time}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Your Location </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.location}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="numberOfPersons">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No of Persons </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.numberOfPersons}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Trip Price</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.price}} </td>
    </ng-container>




    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>


<mat-paginator [pageSize]="6" [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 4, 6, 10, 20]">
</mat-paginator>
```

Ts

```
delete(key) {
  this.ph.scheduledRideSingle.remove(key).then(() => {
    alert('Success');
  });
}
```

Ph.ts

```
[![constructor() {
       this.scheduledRideSingle = firebase.database().ref(`userProfile/ScheduledRides`);

     }



  public scheduledRideSingle: any;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `remove()`:

> `remove`
>
> Removes the data at this Database location.
>
> Any data at child locations will also be deleted.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#remove

For example:

```
var adaRef = firebase.database().ref('users/ada');
adaRef.remove()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Remove succeeded.")
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
  });
```

If you want to delete a particular node then do:

```
firebase.database.ref("userProfile/ScheduledRides").child(key).remove();
```

Comment: thanks. Will try out and give  feedback. However i have updated my question please check it out.

Comment: Okay I saw the image, in ur database u have `userProfile` node and under it you have an ID, you need to access that ID to be able to delete ScheduledRides

Comment: `firebase.database.ref("userProfile").child(uid). child("ScheduledRides").remove();`

Comment: Yeah it did. Thanks

Comment: this solved it `delete(uid) {
  firebase.database().ref(`/userProfile/${uid}/ScheduledRides`).remove().then(() => {
alert('Successfully Deleted');
  });
}`

Comment: correct, you need to traverse the database from up to down, to be able to delete the node

Comment: Yeah, Thanks putting me through though